# TDlib monitors multiple accounts, how to distinguish new messages received 。Based on java

Tags: java, telegram, tdlib

- Based on TDlib, I now implement time monitoring for multiple account clients. Whenever I receive UpdateNewMessage, how should I distinguish which account client this message belongs to?
  Based on java

I can now receive messages from multiple account clients, but I can’t tell which client they are from.
Based on java